# How to use jQuery on to attach to the click event of a button by ID

Tags: jquery, events, click

```
    //Add solve puzzle buttons
    jSolvePuzzleButtonsHTML = "<div><button id=\"bsolveacross\">solve word across</button><button id=\"bsolvedown\">solve word down</button><button id=\"bsolvepuzzle\">solve puzzle</button></div>";
    jQuery("#gridpuzzlewrapper").append(jSolvePuzzleButtonsHTML);

    jQuery("#bsolvedown").on('click', '#bsolvedown', function() {
        alert("click called...");
    });
```

For some reason my click event is not firing.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create proper elements with event handlers:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    var div  = $('<div />'),
        btn1 = $('<button />', {
                                 id   : 'bsolveacross',
                                 text : 'solve word across'
                               }
        ),
        btn2 = $('<button />', {
                                 id   : 'bsolvedown',
                                 text : 'solve word down',
                                 on   : {
                                        click: function() {
                                                        alert("click called...");
                                                          }
                                       }
                               }
        ),
        btn3 = $('<button />', {
                                 id   : 'bsolvepuzzle',
                                 text : 'solve puzzle'
                                }
        );

    $("#gridpuzzlewrapper").append( div.append(btn1, btn2, btn3) );
});
```

written with lots of whitespace to show how elements are created with objects setting event handlers and attributes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery("#bsolvedown").click( function() {
  alert("click called...");
});
```

Comment: None of those seem to be firing either. There I tried clearing my cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#bsolvedown").on('click', function() {
    alert("click called...");
});
```